# Php 7 and xDebug configuration

Tags: php, xdebug

I have just migrated to php7 and i installed xdebug.

I noticed that the xdebug now displays the File and line number when we `var_dump` something.

Example:

```
<?php
var_dump(1);
var_dump('a');
var_dump([1,2,3,'a']);
?>
```

would displays as:

```
/path/to/project/index.php:3:int 1

/path/to/project/index.php:4:string 'a' (length=1)

/path/to/project/index.php:5:
array (size=4)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
  3 => string 'a' (length=1)
```

this is quite nice and very helpful, but can we make the `file info` and result on separate line to make it easier to read?

like:

```
/path/to/project/index.php:3:
int 1

/path/to/project/index.php:4:
string 'a' (length=1)

/path/to/project/index.php:5:
array (size=4)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
  3 => string 'a' (length=1)
```